# WebElement methods not showing

Tags: python, selenium

[My target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCxsg.png)

I am trying to access the methods of a web element after I have stored it in a list. 
I am trying to access the elements in each row-search class element

```
table = browser.find_element_by_class_name("search-reports")
results = table.find_elements_by_class_name("div")

for panel in results:

    panel.find_element_by_tag("h2")
```

'WebElement' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_tag'

The methods in panel are not showing. I have looked at other questions/tutorials and I can't seem to see what I am missing.

I can access the methods on the table variable but just not on results array.

Answer (score 0):

The function is `find_element_by_tag_name()`, not `find_element_by_tag()`

By the way, `<div>` is also tag, not class attribute. `results` will be an empty list.

Comment: Problems are still persisting after the changes but thanks for the heads up! Just found another way to work around it!